# Is Java Antlr4 grammar somehow finished?

Tags: antlr4

I noticed that `additiveExpression` is never used here: [https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java8/Java8Parser.g4#L1276`](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java8/Java8Parser.g4#L1276%60)

(Used only in itself and in `shiftExpression`)

Is it by design or Java grammar is far from completeness?

Comment: The Java grammars require a lot of work. The java8 grammar is ancient. The current spec is version 19. Neither java8 nor java9 are optimized. The grammars should be scraped from spec, not typed in by hand. People have been adding things piecemeal at a time, often in contradiction with the spec with no scientific basis. The testsuites are pitifully small. I am planning to redo all the java grammars, but haven't found the time yet.

Comment: Sorry, I understand WHY things can be unfinished, I just need a confirmation that it IS unfinished?

Comment: It is unfinished, for example, it's not optimized. But, the `additiveExpression` is correct in so far as it is exactly per spec https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html. It does parse expressions, including addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot answer if the Java ANTLR4 grammar is finished (when is a grammar ever finished?) and @kaby76 gave you some information, but I can explain why the `additiveExpression` rule is only used in `shiftExpression` and nowhere else. The reason is that this is how complex expressions are defined in ANTLR4 grammars. You start with a top level rule and (depending on the precedence) define sub rules that handle smaller sub parts of an expression, thereby distributing the actual work over multiple sub rules that together handle the entire expression. The rule `additiveExpression` is such a sub rule, responsible for the addition or subtraction of two further subrules (here `multiplicativeExpression`).

There's no other other situation where this sub rule would be needed. It makes sense only in expression parsing.

Comment: So, given grammar can't parse addition and is very unfinished in this regard?

Comment: Yes, if the grammar cannot parse a specific expression then it must be improved. But keep in mind for which Java version a grammar is written. Usually however, a grammar should be kind of finished when it ends up in the grammar repository, but so often, things are not like they should be.